# Error uploading the required certificate and profiles through fastlane to S3

Tags: gitlab-ci, fastlane-match

I'm currently trying to store my certs and provisioning profiles in a S3 Bucket.

When I run the fastlane match development/appstore command I get the following log

```
[09:12:22]: Error accessing file, this might be due to fastlane's directory handling
[09:12:22]: Check out https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/#directory-behavior for more details

/Users/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.181.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:67:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /var/folders/qq/2q6btwss76s75cmdj84q06nw0000gn/T/d20230828-3086-toqw67/android/ (Errno::ENOENT)
```

I am trying to upload my certificates and provisiong profiles into the S3 bucket.
This is how my Matchfile looks like:

```
s3_bucket("***")
s3_region("***")
storage_mode("s3")
type("development")
```

I have passed the access key ID and secrets key access in as env varibale in .zshrc file.

**NOTE: FastlaneVersion:2.214.0**